# Radio buttons fire in VB net at form load

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple VB net form with two radio buttons in a group box and button outside the group box that calls another form that sets up other parameters.  The radio buttons both send data over the serial port. 
Form1_load event has a boolean value `form_loading = True`. This is checked in the rbtn handler and if true should exit the subroutine. On debug, the check changed even fires one button's event that is checked at design time and at this point the `form_loading` value is  set to false and I have no idea why. There is no `form_loading = false` statement. If I remove the rbtn handler, the `form_loading = True` persists when the other form is called and returned. The groupbox with buttons is activated as it sees a rbtn1-CheckChanged when the form loads and  `form_loading` value get set to false. I suspect that the rbtn event is firing as the form begins to load, before the `form_loading = True` statement is reached, but how do I stop it firing the button event?
As its stands, when debug start, there is an IO exception error:

> Serialport is closed, and the code associated with the button is in
>   the buffer to send to a (closed) com port

```
Private Sub rbtnDon_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rbtnDon.CheckedChanged
    If form_loading Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf rbtnDoff.Checked = True Then 'event fires when other button checkchanged = true,  this stops it
        Exit Sub
    Else
        data_out = (SOT + "N" + EOT)
        SendtoBoard(data_out)
    End If
End Sub`enter code here`
```

Comment: _"Form1_load event has a boolean value"_ i dont understand this. Maybe you should include the `Form1_load`. Because if that is a local variable in that event handler you should not be able to access it here. It's initialil value is `true` and there is no code which sets it to `false`? Then it's impossible that it's `false` in `rbtnDon_CheckedChanged`.

Comment: Set `form_loading` variable in form's `New()` method or use reverse logic - declare `form_loaded` and set it `true` after form is loaded/activated.

Comment: The VB.NET IDE hides the constructor of a Form, that is not helping you.  Type "Sub New" and press Enter.  And do consider changing your UI, it is generally wise to only do something non-trivial when a radio button gets checked.  So you'd favor the CheckedChanged event handler of another button to do this.

Comment: `ElseIf rbtnDoff.Checked = True Then` >> maybe should be == because here you are checking the rbtnDoff...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Everyone. Elsewhere I found this tip: Remove the "handles rbtnDon checkchanged" from the sub:

Private Sub rbtnDon_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)handles rbtnDon checkchanged

and add this to the form1_load sub:

AddHandler rbtnDon.CheckedChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf rbtnDon_CheckedChanged)

That seems to have solved the problem completely.

I could not add the startup code on my original post as for some reason the box will not accept two lots  of separate code  - or I am not doing it right:
It is here:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    For i As Integer = 0 To My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames.Count - 1
        ccbComPort.Items.Add(My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames(i))
    Next
    If ccbComPort.Items Is Nothing Then
        lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblMessage.Text = "No Serial Ports found"
    Else
        ccbComPort.Text = My.Settings.oldPort
    End If
    ccbBaudrate.Text = My.Settings.oldBaud
    pnlComPorts.Visible = True
    'form_loading = True

    rbtnDon.Enabled = True
    AddHandler rbtnDon.CheckedChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf rbtnDon_CheckedChanged)
End Sub
```

Originally I had one form with a panel for the Com port setup and everything was fine, the issue only started when I moved the port set up to form2, after which the rbtnDon event fired before form1 started.
 I did try the Sub New() approach but then I just get a small blank form on debug. Adding Form1_load to it results in "NotImplemented Exception".

The method described above seems OK and fairly simple to add but maybe it is not good practice?